# Is there any way to speed up extraction using tesseract OCR Engine, while tiff file is having 600-700 pages?

Tags: tesseract, tiff, libtiff

During processing of tiff files, which are having **600 - 700 pages** from Tesseract OCR engine with hocr option, we monitored that files are taking around **40 - 50 minutes**.

We monitored that it is so much time for processing large files.

Do we have any way to speed up the process?

Following command is using: -

```
<Drive>:\Tesseract-OCR>tesseract.exe "Source_Tiff_File" "Destination_File" hocr
```

Comment: In the svn there is a new contribution from AMD which uses OpenGL and seems to brings a speed improvement of 50% or more.

Comment: Hi, out of curiosity how many `mb` is the 600-700 page `tif`?  maybe you could try some of the new GPU instances from `aws` or `azure` and leverage the `OpenCL` and `Cuda` patches mentioned above (Not `OpenGL`).  I'm hoping to try this for one of my projects also.

Answer (score 1):

You can split up the multi-page TIFF and run them in multiple processes.

Comment: Because, we read text and coordinate from html file; so again I will have to merge the data and coordinate from all html files, and consolidate into one that will be extra overhead in processing.